# AngularJS - Include variable in directive callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to have my directive pass arguments to the caller, but I cannot get it to work.

Note: I **can** call the function without arguments. But as soon as I add arguments, it breaks:

Here is the Plunker: (http://embed.plnkr.co/autsgiBlWjz8cX2BL6Sj/preview)

For your reference, here is the code:

// Code goes here
    angular
      .module('myApp', []);

```
angular
  .module('myApp') 
  .directive('myDirective', myDirective)
  .controller('ParentController', ParentController);  

function myDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: {},
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: {
      myCallback: '&'
    },
    scope: {},
    template: '<div><button data-ng-click="myCallback({msg:123})Call Callback</button></div>'
  };
}

function ParentController() {
  var self = this;

  self.parentCallback = parentCallback;

  function parentCallback(args) {
    alert('The message is: ' + args.msg);
  }
}
```

HTML code here:

```
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.45" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.45/angular2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="ParentController as ctrl">
      <my-directive my-callback="ctrl.parentCallback(args)"></my-directive>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolate scope via an
>   expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of
>   local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For
>   example, the hideDialog function takes a message to display when the
>   dialog is hidden. This is specified in the directive by calling
>   close({message: 'closing for now'}). Then the local variable message
>   will be available within the on-close expression.

If you want to receive `args` in that way, `<my-directive>`'s template should be like below.

```
<div><button data-ng-click="myCallback({args: {msg:123}})">Call Callback</button></div>
```